# PL/SQL error - need instructions

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g

I need help with some pl/sql error. I need to write function whitch extract frist three numbers from text file and use it later. To do so, I wrote this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_dep
   (v_filename IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   v_filehandle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   v_deptno       NUMBER;
   v_fileline     VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   v_filehandle:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('/home/oracle/vezba', v_filename, 'r');
   UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_filehandle, v_fileline);
   v_deptno:=TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(v_fileline,1,3));
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_filehandle);
   RETURN v_deptno;
END extract_dep;
/

VARIABLE g_deptno NUMBER
EXECUTE :g_deptno:=extract_dep('POVECANJE.txt');
```

After executing this I get this error

```
Function created
begin :g_deptno:=extract_dep('POVECANJE.txt'); end;
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "HR.EXTRACT_DEP", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Content of 'POVECANJE.txt' are numbers 100200. What I'm supposed to do? I checked for the file path and it's correct. Don't know what to do, so if anyone know the solution please tell.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Oracle 11.2 "Supplied packages and types" documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70913), the directory specification used in `utl_file.fopen()` function must be a directory object. In other words, you can't use an absolute path in your `.fopen()` call, but need to have a directory defined (by your DBA usually, as these are "global" DB objects) by ...

```
create directory dir_vezba as '/home/oracle/vezba';
```

... and granted to the DB user you are using for the file import ...

```
grant read on directory dir_vezba to your_db_schema_name_here;
```

... and use the directory object as parameter to your `.fopen()` call ...

```
v_filehandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_VEZBA', v_filename, 'r');
```

If your `your_db_schema_here` user has DBA privileges or the `read any directory` privilege, you may omit the `grant read on directory ...` part.